# Azure bicep Failed to install .NET runtime v5.0. in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-bicep

I am running into the error Failed to install .NET runtime v5.0. when using bicep in visual studio code on a windows machine.

[image: vs code bicep error]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not able to find it automatically, but manually specifying the dotnet path in settings.json resolved the problem.

```
"dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
    {
        "extensionId": "ms-azuretools.vscode-bicep",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
    }
]
```